# com.facebook.react.bridge.readablenativemap cannot be cast to java.lang.string in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using React native with Redux-saga. When I try to pass value saga true my back end...I got an error message like this. And I have already tried the same question answer in StackOverflow, But this answer did not work for me. I am a student, so I don't know much more. If anyone can help me with this, I really grateful to you all.❤️

```
function addUserPassMailChild(email, password) {
    auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('User account created & signed in!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                console.log('That email address is already in use!');
            }

            if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                console.log('That email address is invalid!');
            }

            console.error(error);
        });
}

export function* addUserPassMail(action) {
    const email = action.payload.email;
    const password =action.payload.password;
    console.log(email, password)

    try {
        const emailLogin = yield call(addUserPassMailChild, {email:email, password:password})

        if (emailLogin) {
            // console.log(loginData.additionalUserInfo.profile)
            yield put(AddUserSuccess(emailLogin))
            yield put({
                type: GET_USER_TOKEN_LISTENER,
            })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        yield put(AddUserField(error))
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing arguments like this:

```js
yield call(addUserPassMailChild, email, password);
```

Or try getting the arguments like this:

```js
function addUserPassMailChild({email, password}) {
// TODO
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir...❤️